# Can't get the array data from addSnapshotListener

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am reading the data from firestore database. But i cant take these data and add to my array in the class.
While running the app, whenever i click the TrueFalseVC, it gives me this error next to this func

Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

```
 func getQuestionText() -> String {
        return quiz[questionNumber].question
}
```

my TrueFlaseVC

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TrueFalseVC: 

    UIViewController {
    
        //Outlets
        @IBOutlet weak var trueBtn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var falseBtn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var questionLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
        @IBOutlet weak var scoreLbl: UILabel!
        
        private var trueFalseBrain = TrueFalseBrain()
        private var quizRef: CollectionReference!
        private var quizListener: ListenerRegistration!
        private var quiz = [TrueFalse]()
        var selectedCategory = ""
        
        //MARK: ViewWillAppear
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            setListener()
          
        }
        
        //MARK: ViewDidLoad
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            quizRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(TRUEFALSE_REF)
            
            trueBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            falseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            updateUI()
        }
        
        //MARK: ViewWillDisappear
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            quizListener.remove()
        }
        
        func setListener() {
            quizListener =  quizRef
                    .whereField(GAME, isEqualTo: selectedCategory)
                    .addSnapshotListener {(snapshot, error) in
                     if let err = error {
                         debugPrint("Error fetching data \(err)")
                     }else {
                        self.trueFalseBrain.quiz.removeAll()
                        self.quiz = TrueFalse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                     }
                 }
            
            }
        
     
        
        @objc func updateUI(){
            setListener()
            
            questionLbl.text = getQuestionText()
            progressBar.progress = getProgress()
            scoreLbl.text = "Score: \(getScore())"
            
        }
        
        
        //MARK: QUIZ BRAIN
        //Variables
        var questionNumber = 0
        var score = 0
    
    
        func getQuestionText() -> String {
                return quiz[questionNumber].question
        }
    }
```

My TrueFalse Class is:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class TrueFalse {
    private(set) var question: String!
    private(set) var answer: String!
    private(set) var game: String!
    
    init(question:String, answer:String, game:String){
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.game = game
    }

    class func parseData(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?) -> [TrueFalse]{
        var quiz = [TrueFalse]()
        guard let snap = snapshot else {return quiz}
        for document in snap.documents {
            let data = document.data()
            let question = data[QUESTION] as? String ?? ""
            let answer = data[ANSWER] as? String ?? ""
            let game = data[GAME] as? String ?? ""

            
            let newQuestion = TrueFalse(question: question, answer: answer, game: game)
               quiz.append(newQuestion)
        }
        
        return quiz
 
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: The classic asynchronous trap: The database request inside `setListener` works asynchonously and when  `getQuestionText` is called the data is not available (yet). You need a completion handler or call  `getQuestionText` in the closure of `setListener`.

Comment: How can i add the completion handler to this function?